# How to center align, ignoring certain characters?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

Look at this `UILabel`. It's center-aligned:

[image]

---

Now look at this `UILabel`.  Although it is technically center-aligned, it really doesn't look that way:

[image]

---

The reason why it looks like this is because the center-alignment considers the degree symbol a third character, thus bumping the other two off to the left a bit.  My question is: is there any way to ignore certain characters whilst center-aligning a label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. The only solution that comes to mind for me is to pad the `text` string with spaces on the front to cancel out the ignored characters on the back.

That is, to center `@"60d"` as if it were `@"60"`, set the `text` to `@" 60d"`. This works well with a fixed width font, but otherwise is only a rough approximation.

If you like this idea and want to get fancy with it, then you can use `NSString`s method

```
– stringByPaddingToLength:withString:startingAtIndex:
```

perhaps in conjunction with `– rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` or some such method to determine how many spaces to pad with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I thought about using a space, but it doesn't seem precise.  I'll check it out and see, though. ;)

Comment: @sudo: It won't be precise if the font isn't fixed width. I'll be curious to check back see what solutions other people come up with.

Comment: Well, it's `Helvetica Light`.  Not sure if that's fixed-width or not.

Comment: @sudo: Courier New is the only fixed-width font on the iPhone, and it looks terrible.

Answer (score 1):

You could of course measure the text string(s) and compute your own positioning, rather than using text alignment in a larger field.

Assuming you don't want to do that, another idea that comes to mind is to display the string “°60°” with the first character styled with a color of opacity 0 and no shadow.

I don't do iOS development so I don't know how practical these are.